# Flask Default logger is missing timestamp

Tags: python, flask, logging

I am trying to use the default logger for my Flask app, but the log lines do not include timestamps. When I looked at the source code for Flask on GitHub (https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/logging.py), I saw that the default formatter does include a timestamp. However, when I use the default formatter in my code, the log lines only include the message, source, and level, and not the timestamp.

Logging lines in controller:

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import current_app as app

class HealthCheckController(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        app.logger.info("added logs here")
```

Output:

```
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77757] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77757] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (77757)
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77757] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77758] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77758
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77759] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77759
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77760] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77760
[2023-01-02 16:27:46 +0530] [77761] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77761
INFO:src:added logs here
```

Comment: You have the timestamp right there, the first part on each line is the timestamp

Comment: @YusufIpek those log lines are from gunicorn workers check last line it's missing timestamp

Answer (score 0):

The flask logger also in background uses the default python logging class, so you can just directly use `logging` instead of `app.logger`. Try something like:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

At the start of your app do this and then the following should work

```py
>>> logging.info('an info messge')
2023-01-03 15:28:28 INFO     an info messge
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but using the logging module would require the logger instance to be passed across modules or each one would require a separate instance of a logger

Comment: Yep, so I create a separate file to set logger settings / format, say `custom_logger.py` in which I do `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and then import this `logger` everywhere.